# Why is there a need for a try block before catch in exception handling c++

Tags: c++, exception

Is it possible to throw an exception and catch it without using a try block ?
ex:

```
int main()
{
    throw 1;
    catch(int){
       std::cerr << "caught exception\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: No. (some padding)

Comment: Why, of course you can!  here: `int main() { std::cerr << "caught exception\n"; return 0; }`

Comment: @MikeNakis: What?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit What what? C-:=

Comment: catch cannot exist without try. why you want that??!!!

Comment: @HussenBaban that's because if you throw an exception and then immediately catch it, then these two operations cancel each other out, right?  There is a long tradition of carefully formulating imprecise statements so as to indicate what parts of the statement are literally meant as they are, and which parts are optional / indicative only, but you do not appear to be of that tradition.  Expounding about it in the body of the question would have perhaps exonerated you, but you wrote a one-liner. Why should people put effort into an answer when you have not put any effort into your question?

Comment: @MikeNakis Well I didn't want to waste people's time in reading a long explanation for a simple question but  you're right My explanation was a bit too short I edited the question title to clarify it and WhiZTiM already answered and thanks for helping.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

There is a slight difference in the behavior of program control flow during an exception in flight. `try-catch` blocks hopefully brings the program back to the usual control flow.

When an exception is thrown at any point in the program. *Normal program control* flow halts. The program control flow now goes through the runtime's mechanism for exception handling. This is different from what is *normal*. For the *normal*, destructors for automatic storage always runs when control flow reaches the end of scope *(lifetime)* **"`}`"**. For exceptions in flight, they run *earlier* than *normal*

Consider this (note the comments);

```
MyClass foo(){
{
    MyClass c;
    c.call(balhhh); //assuming this throws

    // (1)

    ....
    return c;
 }

void bar(){
     std::map<K,V> mp;
     auto c = foo();

     // (2)

     mp.insert(c);
     ....
}
```

When you call `bar`, we can see how control flow is per-maturely leaves `foo()` at `// (1)`, no other code after `// (1)` is executed within the scope of `foo()`, the same thing happens when `foo()` has been unwound, and we are now at `// (2)`

This happens throughout stack-unwinding process, And this recursively unwinds all functions... until we are back to `main()` where `std::terminate` is called.

---

Now, with a *try-catch* block, the compiler generates code that suspends that *early* exit behavior after program has moved to a catch block (in search for a matching handler), and if the exception is handled, control flow goes back to normal.

Consider:

```
MyClass foo() 
    try {
        MyClass c;
        c.call(balhhh); //assuming this throws

        // (1)

        ....
        return c;
     }
     catch(...){
          ...
     }

void bar(){
     std::map<K,V> mp;
     auto c = foo();

     // (2)

     mp.insert(c);
     ....
}
```

Now, when the exception leaves, control flow leaves the norm at `// (1)` to search for the handler in the associated `catch`, if the exception was handled, the program goes back to the *normal* control flow. Code after `// (2)` will execute now...

---

As you can see from the explanation, *try-catch* blocks are the only way as dictated by C++ standards, to restore *normal* program control flow after an exception is thrown.

```
int main()
{
    throw 1;   //fine, program control leaves the whole of main at this point.
    catch(int){    //illegal, like using an else block without an if
       std::cerr << "caught exception\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Even if the above code was legal, `throw` means control will leave the whole of the enclosing scope at the `throw` site.

Comment: Really struggling to follow this answer. How does it address the question posed?

Comment: what are you trying to explain? The question was - `Is it possible to throw an exception and catch it without using a try block?`

Comment: @AbhinavGauniyal, Perhaps, you didn't see the question written as *"Why write try block before catch block in exception handling c++"*. That's fine. You can look up the title again. To your question about what I was trying to explain; If it's too long for you to read, I'll graciously summarize it:- I explained the concept of control flow when exceptions are in flight and when they are not; and how *try-catch* block helps the semmatics of the language and codegen.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, I'll admit, the first edit was a bit rough. I've cleaned it up now. To your question, *"How does it address the question posed?"* :- The OP kinda asked two different questions in the title and the body (check for yourself). I simply tried to elaborate on the concept of control-flow and how *try-catch* comes into play

Answer (score 1):

According to my experience, you have to use try and catch block in a combination. Here if any error occur in the try block then only it is passed to the catch block. Thus if there is no try block then it won't know where to look for the error. Thus they need to be used in combination. I am not sure in C++ but in Java you can use catch block in singly if you extend the class to throwable.

Comment: Don't know why this was downvoted?? By people who themselves have no clue how C++ exceptions work, perhaps?